# What do the magical numbers mean in this Franck-Hertz experiment source code?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics

I'm trying to model a Franck-Hertz experiment. I found this source code - https://github.com/PhysicsProjects/Franck-and-Hertz-Experiment , and I want to use this code as the basis of my program. I will indicate the author. But I don't understand the meaning of these numbers: -10.88, 66.92, 1.3829202595488537 (especially the last).

Here is the source code of the compute function:

```
function comptuteValue (value) {

    var period = 4.9
      , low = 6
      ;

    var y = 0;
    if (value > period && value % period > 0 && value % period < 0.3) {
        if (value <= period * 2) {
            y = -10.88 * value + 66.92;
        } else {
            y = comptuteValue (value - period) + 2 * Math.floor(value / period);
        }
    } else {
        if (value <= period) {
            return Math.pow (value, 3/2) * 1.3829202595488537;
        } else {
            return comptuteValue (value - period) + 2 * Math.floor(value / period);
        }
    }

    return y;
}
```

Comment: Does this help http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1.3829202595488537 ? $150/343\sqrt{10}$ there is a power to $3/2$ next to one of the magic numbers perhaps it is that suggestion from wolframalpha...

Comment: This number look like physical constant. So many digits after the decimal point.

Comment: "Magic numbers" like this are considered bad form for precisely this reason. Either way, you definitely have to add more information, at the very least what this function is meant to calculate. No one is going to be able to tell you why 66.92 was picked if they don't have more context than "it's in the compute function."

Comment: Agreed, magic numbers are terrible programming style. Also terrible programming style is defining variables on separate lines using the same type declaration. Either one variable per type decl. or use one line for the type decl., don't use both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For readers who need an overview of the Franck-Hertz experiment, see [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franck%E2%80%93Hertz_experiment).

From context, the "value" parameter passed to the comptuteValue (sic) function is the voltage, in Volts, between the cathode and the gate of the vacuum tube, and the function's output is the corresponding current, in Amperes, that flows between the cathode and the anode.

The 4.9 in the code is the 4.9 eV smallest excitation energy of a mercury atom. When the applied voltage is less than the 4.9V needed for an electron from the cathode to excite a mercury atom, the current is "space charge limited", and the value of the current is given by [Child's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_charge#Child's_law):

$$I=\frac{4 \epsilon_0}{9}\sqrt{2 e / m_e} \frac{S}{d^2}V^{3/2}\ ,$$

where $\epsilon_0$ is the [vacuum permittivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_permittivity), $e$ and $m_e$ are an electron's charge and mass, $S$ is the anode surface area, and $d$ is the distance between the cathode and anode. Child's law is what the following line of code is computing:

```
return Math.pow (value, 3/2) * 1.3829202595488537;
```

The value 1.3829202595488537 is the current as given by Child's law, except for the factor $V^{3/2}$. Unfortunately, although $\epsilon_0$, $e$ and $m_e$ are all physical constants that can be looked up, the $S$ and the $d$ depend on the dimensions of the experimental equipment, so it's unclear what values the code is using for those.

The 10.88 and 66.92 describe the linear equation that models the rapid drop-off of current right above the 4.9 V threshold. However, good values for those parameters would depend in complicated ways on the dimensions of the equipment, and were likely just chosen to match the measured I/V curve.

Comment: Seems $S\approx 5d^2$ in the code if I didn't calculate wrong.